# Location.getBearing always 0.0

Tags: android, gps

I'm using `LocationListener` and returned Location always has Bearing as 0.0

Is there anything else I need to do?

I also noticed that with 4.0.3 update I rarely have speed reported. Now I just get positions and accuracy/elevation

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onLocationChanged");

        Position position  = new Position();

            position.PositionGKey = UUID.randomUUID();
            position.GPSTime = new Date(loc.getTime());
            position.DeviceTime = new Date();
            position.Latitude = loc.getLatitude();
            position.Longitude = loc.getLongitude();
            position.Altitude = loc.getAltitude();
            position.Speed = loc.hasSpeed() ? loc.getSpeed() * 2.23693629 : 0;
            position.Accuracy = (int)loc.getAccuracy();
            position.Bearing = loc.hasBearing() ? loc.getBearing() : 0;

            // There was cases with speed reported 1000+. Just make it real here, round of obvious errors.
            if (position.Speed > 120)
            {
                position.Speed = 0.0;
            }

            PositionData.InsertPosition(getApplicationContext(), position);

    }
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code on how you're getting the Location... Some of us might do sorcery, but we're definitely not guessers :)

Comment: Code posted. Point is that 4.0.3 acting differently. I hardly ever get speed and just now I added bearing and never see it logged..

Comment: Is that when using GPS or NETWORK provider?

Answer (score 0):

When using the GPS provider, Bearing is usually not updated / returned unless the device physically moves and gains speed (check getSpeed()). In practice, speed above 1m/s should produce accurate bearings. I've also found that I have had to occasionally poll and check for the last known location on the GPS provider and grab it's updated bearings to get proper readings.